# Open link in a new window in electron

Tags: hyperlink, window, electron, atom-editor

I am using the below code to open a link in a new electron window:

```
$('body').on('click', '.openlink', function () {
    var url = 'https://www.google.com' + this.id;
    window.open(url,"_blank","height=650,width=1000,frame=true,show=true");
});
```

However, when I click the button again, the other page opens in the same window that google.com opened. How can I open new button clicks on new windows every time ?

Comment: check this: [window-open at electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/window-open.md)